# Django admin custom validation - require at least one inline foreign-key model

Tags: django, validation, django-admin, foreign-keys

I have two Django models (Purchaser and LineItem) that I manage via the stock admin interface.  The dumbed-down versions:

```
class Purchaser(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField('First Name', max_length = 30)
    lastname = models.CharField('Last Name', max_length = 30)
    paymentid = models.IntegerField('Payment ID', unique = True)

class LineItem(models.Model):
    purchaser = models.ForeignKey(Purchaser)
    ship_first_name = models.CharField('Recipient First Name', max_length = 50)
    ship_last_name = models.CharField('Recipient Last Name', max_length = 50)
```

I have LineItems as an inline within the Purchaser admin page, and want to require that Purchasers have at least one LineItem (i.e. not let the user save a new Purchaser unless they have added at least one LineItem).  Is there a clean way to do this?  I already have some validation set up using a custom [modelForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541201/how-can-i-create-sophisticated-django-model-validation-for-django-admin), but that method only deals with Purchaser fields, and not anything to do with LineItems.  Advice?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the answer information referenced here: [Django: Forcing admin users to enter at least one item in TabularInline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648563/django-forcing-admin-users-to-enter-at-least-one-item-in-tabularinline)

Hope that helps you out.